# How to get confusion matrix in pytorch?

Tags: python, pytorch

There are 15 classes. I have two tensors, one has the target classes and other has the predicted classes.
How can I get a confusion matrix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using the sklearn package, given you have your target class y_test and predicted class y_pred.

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
print(confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred))
```